# Defining properties of categories out of an indicial category

Tags: ct.category-theory, soft-question, topos-theory

$\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}$Suppose we want to define the category of arrows of $S$. Below are two forms of doing it.

> **Definition 1**: If $D$ is of the following type: $\bullet \to \bullet$, then the category $\Diag(D, S)$ is called the category of arrows of $S$, denoted $\Fl(S)$.

> **Definition 2**: Let $\Delta^1$ be the category associated with the totally ordered set of two elements [0, 1]. So the category of arrows of $S$, denoted $\Fl(S)$ is the category $\Hom(\Delta^1, S)$.

The relationship between the two is evident, but I would like to know the motivation for choosing each one of them.

> **Question**: *When defining properties of categories with an indicial category when is useful to work with the category $\Delta^n$ and when with abstract diagrams.*

Comment: You're using $\Hom(\Delta^1, S)$, $\Diag(D, S)$ and $\Fl(S)$ without defining what those macros should do - that's why they are displayed in red. I have edited your post to show how [you can include such definitions](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/464687/2) - I have added at least definition for Hom, you should probably include the other two as well, so that your post is displayed correctly.

Comment: I really don't understand what's supposed to be meaningfully different about these two definitions.